# Database User Details Security

Tags: php, mysql, database, security, phpmyadmin

My question is probably quite a basic silly one, but here goes anyway:

When a user registers on my site should I store their personal details (name, address, etc.) in a seperate table from their login information (username, password hash, salt) and if so, should there be any relationship or link between the tables?

Comment: Er, yes? I'm not even sure why you're asking this question; it's obvious.

Comment: But should they be linked in anyway?

Comment: Yes. How else are you going to know which details belong to which user, unless you store them in the same table?

Comment: @Jam: I don't see why this is so obvious. Especially I don't see why it would make any difference for security, which this question seems to be targetted at. Moreover, I don't see the obvious general advantages it would have to separate the tables.

Comment: Personally would store user information in an other table if there is a design reason, consider the example of multiple values for the phone number case where a user has many numbers, so basically the ER approach is good to be advised, if it shows no reason to break the table, why to break it.

Comment: @Melsi: This sounds to me more like OP wants to "split" the table and put some columns into a different, 1:1 associated table, which is superflous and breaks normalization. Also, OP seems to think that this is somehow beneficial for security, which is also not the case.

Comment: @NiklasB.: Thats exactly what I was going to do, but I can see you don't recommend this, would you just have one table for all the account details?

Comment: @Campino: I don't know what the best database design would be in your case, but security sure doesn't play a role here.

Comment: @NiklasB.: Okay, thanks for the help, I'll go with your advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Storing them in separate tables don't adds anything for the security aspect.

If you decide to store them separately for some reason, both tables should be linked to determine which login information belongs to who.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter from a security stand point.  Instead, you should think about database design, which is worthy of a Google search.

After you've done your Google research, this may not have been readily apparent.  Take a look at this with special notes on 12 and 15:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/top-20-mysql-best-practices/comment-page-1/#comments

Answer (score 1):

You will still have to link them in some way otherwise you wouldn't know who's who so it would be pointless to do it from a security standpoint.